# In C,how do I make this program return the address of an array,instead of address of first element?

Tags: c

I am really at a loss about this program.I want it to return the address of an integer array of 5 elements.But it just wont' work.How to make a C function return the address of an array instead of the address of its first element(base address)?I know both are same numerically but their types are different,that's why I ask.

Also to put it precisely, how to declare the prototype of such functions?I understand how to declare the argument part of the prototype (using abstract declarators) but just don't know how to declare the return type  if we are to return addresses of arrays or functions.I only know that if we place a '*' before function name in declaration that it means the function returns a pointer to the respective primary data type like int,char or float.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int (*)[5]fun(int (*)[5]);

    int main(void)
    {

    int arr[5];

    printf("%u",fun(&arr));

    }

    int (*)[5]fun(int (*arr_add)[5])
    {
    return arr_add;
    }
```

**HELLO!!**   ***DANIEL FISCHER*** Thanks for your answer.You answered it exactly and in a concise way.But I am choosing H2CO3 's answer as that brilliant Hungarian kid took the trouble to explain it to me in detail through chat.It's really hard to pick the best answer when so many bright people are answering.Thanks everyone!!

Comment: I am sure the (*)[5] before function name in the declaration is totally absurd.I can smell it.But how on earth do we do it if want to mention that the function would be returning things other than simple pointers to int,char or float? How do we signify that it is to return an address of an array or address of a function?

Comment: Aren't "&array_name" and "array_name" different in type?Because "&array_name+1" and "array_name+1" are surely different as former increments by array size while latter increments by size of one element.

Comment: Yes, they are different. One is `int [5]` which can decay into `int *`, the other one is `int (*)[5]`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Exactly!!That's what  I mean to say.If both are different then how can we have the same syntax for a function returning the address of first element of array (base address) and a function returning address of an array?They may be same numerically but not in type.

Comment: @H2CO3 Help me out since u got my point.Everyone else thinks I am a dummy to ask this!!

Comment: "If both are different then how can we have the same syntax for a function returning the address of an array (base address) and a function returning address of an array" - Am I missing something, or you wrote "address of an array" twice? In that case, where's the difference?

Comment: @H2CO3 CORRECTION: I mean how can we have the same syntax for a function returning the address of the first element of an array (base address" and a function returningn address of the array itself.

Comment: we can't. If you return the address of the first element, you return `int *`. If you return the address of the array, you return `int (*)[5]`, that's why that ugly complex declaration is needed. See the update for my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Now you understood EXACTLY what I intend to ask.Yes Sir,what is the correct syntax for that "Ugly complex declaration"? Mine is certainly wrong as it shows error while compiling?How do I declare prototype of a fucntion that returns address of array itself rather than array of first element?Types are different.

Comment: ***Did you read my answer?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
int (*fun(int (*arr)[5]))[5]
{
    return arr;
}
```

If you want to return the address of the **first element** (as opposed to the address of the array itself), that's a different type:

```
int *fun(int (*arr)[5])
{
    return &(*arr)[0];
}
```

Comment: But you are returning address of a pointer in "return &(*arr)[0]!!

Comment: @SheerFish No. `arr` is a pointer to array of 5 `int`. So, `*arr` is an array of 5 `int`. Thus, `(*arr)[0]` is the first element of an array of 5 `int`. And `&(*arr)[0]` is the address of that element. Which, when returned from a function, decays into `int *`. Please don't teach me C.

Comment: My bad!! I had completely missed that point.But Sir,to put it conclusively, can't we explicitly declare in function declaration that the function returns the address of the array itself (of type  int (*)[]) rather than the address of first element of array (of type  int *)?

Comment: I knew intuitively that something like "int (*)[5]fun(int (*)[5]);" looks totally fishy, but how else do I declare a function that returns an address of an array (ie it has type int (*)[]) instead of a function that returns pointer to an int (ie of type int *)?

Comment: @SheerFish Ouch... This is getting tiring... I seriously ask you if you have **at all** read my answer. You're asking this question the second time, and the answer is still in the very beginning of this post here. `int (*fun(int (*arr)[5]))[5]` - Found it? **HALLO, I ANSWERED YOUR QUESTION!** What else, besides bold italic all-caps could I do in order you to finally notice that?

Comment: @But that is function definition isn't it, not the declaration?In declaration we don't use the parameter name (ie arr) for the function "fun" but we use abstract declarators,isn't it?

Comment: @SheerFish You **can** omit the argument name in the declaration, if you want. It's not obligatory.

Comment: Yeah, got it.Let me digest what you have answered this far first.It all seems little difficult for me to grasp in one go.Anyways,East Europeans like you Hungarians are way brighter in Maths and programming.It's a well known fact.What's the secret?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28149/discussion-between-h2co3-and-sheer-fish)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps explaining how it works is of some use.

The idea behind C's declaration syntax is that "declaration mimics use". So you want

- a function

  ```
  fun( )
  ```
- taking a pointer to an array of five `int`

  ```
  fun(int (*arr)[5])  // or without argument name fun(int(*)[5])
  ```
- and returning a pointer

  ```
  (*fun(int (*arr)[5]))
  ```
- to an array of five

  ```
  (*fun(int (*arr)[5]))[5]
  ```
- `int`

  ```
  int (*fun(int (*arr)[5]))[5];
  ```

Or, you can also go from the result, that should be a pointer to an array of five `int`,

```
int (*result)[5];
```

and substitute `result` with the call (`result = fun(arr)`)

```
int (*fur(arr))[5];
```

and then add the type of the argument/replace the argument with its type:

```
int (*fun(int(*)[5]))[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
printf("%u",fun(&arr));
```

It should really be:

```
printf("%p", (void*)fun(&arr));
```

As for the address of the array, it is going to be the same as the address of its first element.

Now, the declaration and definition should really look like:

```
int (*fun(int(*)[5]))[5];
```

Fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int (*fun(int (*)[5]))[5];

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];

    printf("%p\n", (void*)fun(&arr));
}

int (*fun(int (*arr_add)[5]))[5]
{
    return arr_add;
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/LbfOga)

Comment: But aren't "&arr" and "arr" different as they have different types?Because arr+1 and &arr+1 surely mean different things.One increments by the size of one element while the other increments by the size of the array.

Comment: @SheerFish Yes, exactly. The types are different, the values are the same.

Comment: I've updated/corrected the answer. The types of `&arr` and `arr` are different, but the pointer values are the same.

Comment: *Perhaps* the values are the same, if the representations for the different pointer types are the same. If not, then converting one pointer to the type of the other (or converting them both to `void *`) before comparing will prove that *they point to the same place*. I think that's what @H2CO3 meant.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Yes, exactly.